# Getting a reference to the object which is trying to create me

Tags: java, object

Let's say there is a class called Node and another class called Table. A node object can create a Table object. Obviously then the Table class' constructor is called. Is it possible to get from within the Table constructor, a reference to the Node object which is creating this Table instance? One way is if while creating the object, I force the Node object to pass "this" as a parameter to the Table constructor. Is there any other way where no parameter needs to be passed?

Comment: Let it be known that if you were so able to access an object, this would be a poor design choice for readability as well as for performance. This would create unnecessary overhead and obfuscate your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to get a reference to the "calling" object (the instance calling a method, constructor, etc.) in the Java language is to pass the "`this`" object reference to the "receiver" method which needs to know.  There is no other way using plain Java, AFAIK.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can use Thread.getCurrentThread.getStackTrace() to access to the call stack and find out the class name that called it. e.g.

```
Thread.getCurrentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getClassName();
```

But if you want to access the instance of that object then I think the only way to access it is to pass 'this' to the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete Example

```
public class GivesNameOfCallingClass {
//constructor
    public GivesNameOfCallingClass() {
        try {
            throw new Exception("Error");
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getStackTrace()[1].getClassName());
        }
    }
}
```

And Test Class

```
public class GetNameOfCallingClassTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new GivesNameOfCallingClass();
    }
}
```